# Announcing a Pro Tempore Moderator election

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Writing Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://writing.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **July 29** to bring in one more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on July 29, users can [nominate themselves](https://writing.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On August 5, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, we'll announce the results on meta on August 12.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: Does this mean that Writing is getting one step closer to graduating?

Comment: @NofP more that we held off asking for another pro-tem mod thinking a graduation election might be coming soon, but since those wheels are turning slowly and we need the help with our increased activity, we asked for a pro-tem election now.

Comment: I think this question title would be a lot clearer if it included the word "moderator". "Pro tempore" is internal SE jargon, and I would suggest avoiding it.

Comment: It's hardly "internal," but adding "moderator" can't hurt, sure :)

Comment: See [2019 Community Moderator Election](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2126/2533)

Comment: Best of luck Cyn and Secespitus!

Comment: The election has just begun :)